# Every vector is an eigenvector?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am very confused about eigenvectors with my newest discovery.

$v$ and $\lambda$ are defined so that the equation holds:

$$Av = \lambda v.$$

If we pick a normalized v then the equation can be rewritten:

$$
v^T A v = \lambda
$$

However at this point it seems to me like every normalized vector $v$ fulfils the equation, which is false.

So, where is the mistake?

Comment: Its not true that the equation can be rewritten like that, because you cannot go backwards

Comment: You would need to show that $v^TAv=\lambda$ implies $Av=\lambda v$. How would you do that? Note that $vv^T\ne 1$ (it's an $n\times n$ matrix), so it doesn't help to multiply with $v$ from the left.

Comment: If you have a linear operator $A$ on an inner product space $V$ then you can take $\langle v,Av\rangle = c(v)$ for any $v \in V$, where $c(v) \in \mathbb K$,  but that doesn't mean that $c(v)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ nor that $A$ has one

Comment: Your argument would be like "solving" $2x=6$ as follows: "Multiply both sides by 0. You get $0x=0$. So all values of $x$ are solutions."  Just because everything solves some *consequence* of the original equation doesn't mean that everything solves the original equation.

Answer (score 1):

Its not true that the equation can be rewritten like that, because you cannot go backwards. For instance if $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ then $Ae_1=A\binom{1}{0} =\binom10= e_1$ and $Ae_2=A\binom01=-\binom01=-e_2$, and then $(\frac{e_1+e_2}{\sqrt2})^TA(\frac{e_1+e_2}{\sqrt2})=0$, but $\frac{e_1+e_2}{\sqrt2}$ is not an eigenvector, nor does $A$ have eigenvalue $0$.